# C++ OverLoading the << again

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

So my code is compiling ok - however it is not doing what i hoped :(.

Ill try and explain this as best I can -

Below is my code that is writing to a file on disk.

```
void NewSelectionDlg::PrintInfoFile()
{
     **CProductListBox b;**
     ofstream outdata;
     outdata.open("test.dat", ios::app); // opens the file & writes if not there.  ios:app - appends to file
     if( !outdata ) 
     { // file couldn't be opened
      cerr << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
      exit(1);
     }

     outdata << m_strCompany << endl;
     outdata << m_strAppState << endl;
     outdata << m_strPurpose << endl;
     outdata << m_strChannel << endl;
     outdata << m_strProductName << endl;
     **outdata << b << endl;**
     outdata << endl;
     outdata.close();
     return;
}
```

The key lines im concerned about are in Bold.  I want to print out a class CProductListBox.  Now as this is not a string, etc I know I have to over-ride the << in order to be able to do this.  So my class for CProductListBox looks like this:

```
class CProductListBox : public CListBox
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CProductListBox)

public:
    CProductListBox();
    virtual ~CProductListBox();
    **friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b) 
         {
        return o;        
    }**
```

I have bolded again what i think is important - It is printing nothing on the output file unfortunately were I was hoping it would print the contenets of what is in b (the CProductList class).

Can anyone see something stupid I may be missing - Many Thanks,

Colly (Ireland)

Comment: Your `operator<<` doesn't do anything; if you want to write data to the stream, you need to write the code to write the data to the stream...

Answer (score 4):

Your operator<< does not contain any code attempting to print anything.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b) 
{
  o << b.SomeMember << b.AnotherMember;
  return o;        
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erik - the way I want this too work is if I have three drop downs (we'll call them 1,2,3) - based on these data is displayed in another box (this is the CProductListBox) - lets say if 1,2,3 are selected then ABC will display. If 2,1,3 was selected BAC will display etc. So what I want to do is return the complete contents of this CProductListBox class - is it possible to do just o << b; and then return o? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator<<` is getting called, but it doesn't do anything.  It just returns the stream.

If you want it to write data to the stream, you need to write the code to write data to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to supply some code in

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b) 
{
    return o;        
}
```

Something like this would write b's "name" (assuming b has a getName() that returns a std::string) each time you wrote "b" to the ostream.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b) 
{
    o << b.getName();
    return o;        
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin - the way I want this too work is if I have three drop downs (we'll call them 1,2,3) - based on these data is displayed in another box (this is the CProductListBox) - lets say if 1,2,3 are selected then ABC will display.  If 2,1,3 was selected BAC will display etc.  So what I want to do is return the complete contents of this CProductListBox class - is it possible to do just o << b; and then return o?  Thanks

Comment: If class b contains the values for all three dropdowns, then you can change o << b.getName() to  o << b.getField1() << b.getField2() << b.getField3();  If b doesn't contain the three fields, but you have 3 b's (one for each field), then you need to (outside of the operator<< method) do outdata << b1 << b2 << b3;

Comment: Hi Edwin - I can retrieve the info Ok from the drop down seletions. They are set as strings so I can just use outdata << m_strSelection1 << endl; and this prints the string that was selected. The Prob is with bringing back the info that in the ListBox Display - ive tried the following: friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const CProductListBox& b) { int count = b.GetCount(); for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { CString text; b.GetText(i, text); o << (LPCTSTR)text << “,” << b.GetItemData(i) << endl } return o; }  But it is not working how i had hoped - any thoughts?  Many Thanks.